Is there a way to override a Mac system font
I am using Avenir Next Condensed.ttc which is a Mac system font. This is my client's brand font.
My Mac OS and my Adobe software are all up to date.
The Mac system font does not reproduce well when written to Acrobat PDF from InDesign. The lowercase 'u' X height is higher than all the other lowercase letters.
How can I install a .ttf or .otf version of the font in FontBook and override the Mac system font?
I have tried installing a .ttf version but it seems that InDesign always uses the Mac system font version.

You would be better asking this on Apple Stack Exchange.  System settings and OS questions aren't on topic here. Sorry about that.

Thank you for the suggestion, I'll re-post in the Apple Stack Exchange.

I routinely remove Apple default fonts and replace them with .OTF version. You have to alter the actual files on disc, not use a font manager. Most font managers tend to honor installed system fonts.

Thank you for the suggestion, but I am wary about messing around with the system fonts.
